# Serving dynamic sitemap.xml content

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, xml-sitemap

How can I serve a dynamic `sitemap.xml` file from ASP.NET Core 3.1?

I tried something like:

```
...
public ActionResult SiteMap()
{
    // logic here
    return Content("<sitemap>...</sitemap>", "text/xml");
}
...
```

Comment: For situations like this is often nice to have an external process generating the sitemap.xml file once a day and then putting it into the root website folder, that way your code doesn't have to know or care about it. How you crawl / index / manage your sitemap is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly the right approach. Of course, assuming you're using the [standard sitemap protocol](https://www.sitemaps.org/) you'll need to:

1. Establish an XML declaration (e.g., `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)
2. Start with a `<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" />` element

So, for example, if you want to assembly your XML using an `XDocument`, you could start with something like:

```cs
private static readonly XNamespace _sitemapNamespace = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
private static readonly XNamespace _pagemapNamespace = "http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-pagemap/1.0";

public ActionResult Sitemap() {
  var xml = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", String.Empty),
    new XElement(_sitemapNamespace + "urlset",
      //Your logic here
    )
  return Content(sitemap.ToString(), "text/xml");
  );
}
```

That said, with this code, you'll run into an issue with your XML declaration not being returned with your XML, since `XDocument.ToString()` only returns an XML snippet. To fix this, you need to wrap your `XDocument` in e.g. a `StringWriter`:

```cs
var sitemapFile = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(sitemapFile)) {
  sitemap.Save(writer);
}
return Content(sitemapFile.ToString(), "text/xml");
```

> *Note:* There are obviously other approaches for dynamically generating your XML. If you're using an [`XmlWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter?view=netcore-3.1) or an [`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netcore-3.1), your code will look quite different. The point is to help fill out what a real-world implementation *might* look like, not to prescribe an exclusive approach.

Are there specific problems you're running into with your attempt? If so, I may be able to provide more specific guidance. But, as is, the approach you are taking is correct.

Comment: Aside, one of my projects has a [`SitemapController`](https://github.com/OnTopicCMS/OnTopic-Library/blob/master/OnTopic.AspNetCore.Mvc/Controllers/SitemapController.cs) you can reference, if that's useful. That said, the logic is highly specific to our CMS and accounts for a lot of [structured metadata](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data) that you probably don't care about. Nevertheless, it demonstrates one approach for assembling an `XDocument` dynamically and returning it via `Content(xml, "text/xml")`.

Comment: I get a 404 when i try to call it, im not really sure why.

i did try to ad route to it:
...
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                   name: "Sitemap",
                   pattern: "/{page?}/{id?}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", Action = "Sitemap", language = "da" });
...

Comment: my code looks like this

public ActionResult Sitemap()
        {
            // logic here
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF - 8\"?>");
            sb.Append("<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">");
            sb.Append("<url>");
            sb.Append("<loc>>http://www.example.com/</loc>");
            sb.Append("</url>");
            sb.Append("</urlset>");
            return Content(sb.ToString(), "text/xml");
        }

Comment: @Amigo: Most likely, your 404 is due to a routing issue, and not a specific error with your `Sitemap()` action. One potential problem with the route you listed above is that it provides a very general `pattern`, which may be getting superseded by another endpoint. Assuming you only intend to have one main sitemap, I'd consider just adding a `[Route("Sitemap")]` attribute to your controller. Alternatively, if you want to maintain a sitemap-specific route, I'd change your pattern to e.g. `Sitemap`. Note that the leading `/` in your current `pattern` might also be causing problems.

Comment: @Amigo: That said, assuming you already have a route setup for your `HomeController`, you probably don't need to configure an explicit route for your `Sitemap` action. Your default route should address this. Of course, in that case, you'll need to use the pattern `{action?}/{id?}` to ensure that `/Sitemap` gets mapped to the `action` route parameter, and thus the `Sitemap()` action of your `HomeController`.

Comment: cool its working, my route was not correct. i changed pattern to just "sitemap" and all is fine. Thanks a lot for helping Jeremy (y)